# Why are certain days linked with particular deities?

Tags: gods, rituals, astrology

For example, Hanumanji linked with Tuesday, Lord Shiva with Monday, Narayan with thursday etc.

Comment: It's not surprising if you see that weekday is Vara (one of the 5 limbs of Panchanga) and each Panchanga of a day is ruled by some deity or the other. Each Panchanga (including Vara) also have a planetary lord.

Comment: Yeah, traditionally in Pañchāṅga we link it with navagraha, it goes like: 
Monday(Somavāra)- Candra, Tuesday(Maṅgalavāra) - Maṅgala, Wednesday(Budhvāra) - Buddha, Thursday(Br̥haspativāra or Guruvāra) - Br̥haspati, Friday (Śukravāra)- Śukra, Saturday (Śanivāra) - Śani and Sunday (Ravivāra) - Sūrya .  So, here each of the seven planetary deities (Moon, Mars, Mercury, Jupiter, Venus, Saturn, Sun respectively) are linked with each of the days.

Comment: An alternative arrangement is Monday- Śiva, Tuesday- Hanumāna, Gaṇeśa or Murugan/Skanda/Kārtikeya and some also worship Kālī or Durgā on Tues, Wednesday- Viṭhṭhala, Kr̥ṣṇa, Viṣṇu, Thursday- Viṣṇu, Friday- Mahālakṣmī or Śakti, Saturday- Hanumāna, Sunday- Sūrya. Combining it with the navagraha list you get a more detailed list.

Comment: Why are they linked? I guess, to just satisfy the worship needs of various people or because of astrological reasons, or because of different beliefs that a specific day is special for a specific deity.

Answer (score 3):

They're linked because their nature is related to the Graha.

Eg: Hanumaan and Mangala

Why is Mangala the one ruling over Marsday (tuesday) and not Shanaischara or Soma or Surya?

It is the case because of the following derivation:

This is the speed of the Grahas, when observed from earth (since the earth is the center of the Solar system as far as Horaa is concerned), slowest to fastest, as per Surya Siddhanta (among others):

[image: Daily Angular travel of Grahas relative to (relatively still) constellations]

Since the Sun is the ruler of all the Grahas, according to Maharshi Paraashara's Brhat Paaraashara Horaa Shastra...

We assign day 1 and hour (Horaa) one to Surya.

This can also be derived from the basic position of the original speeds. Starting from Saturn, the Sun is the 4th Graha, making it his day from the Naisargika derivation.

Due to reasons (that I won't go into), there have to be 24 hours in a day and not 25 and not 11.

So, when we order the Grahas in this order, starting from day one, Horaa one (we take the days and Horas to begin at sunrise, not at 12 am due to obvious reasons), we get:

Sun - Venus - Mercury - Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars

We give one hour to each of them.

Now, since sunrise, we're at horaa number 7. We repeat this cycle, till we reach the next day:

Sun - Venus - Mercury - Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars -- Sun - Venus - Mercury - Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars -- Sun - Venus - Mercury - Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars **Horaa 21** - Sun - Venus - Mercury **Horaa 24**

Now, the 25th Horaa, aka the Sunrise of the next day, we reach the Moon. Since, the first Horaa is of the Moon, the day also goes to him. So, it's Moonday (Monday).

Repeat this cycle again: Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars - Sun - Venus - Mercury -- Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars - Sun - Venus - Mercury -- Moon - Saturn - Jupiter - Mars - Sun - Venus - Mercury **Horaa 21** - Moon - Saturn - Jupiter **Horaa 24**

Again, we reach Mars's turn when the 24 hours of this day finishes, the sunrise, at the 25th Horaa is of Mars.

Do it again... and again, and that's how you reach them all.

Or, instead of doing all this, you can just do this. Since 25-21 (3 cycles of 7) is 4, you can go in the main list, pick the first day (of Surya), then count including him, 4 places.

That way, you get: **Sun** 4th--> **Moon** 4th --> **Mars** 4th --> **Mercury** etc.

---

Now, why is Shiva linked with Soma? Well, for this you need to read Puranas. Shiva has Chandra (Aka Soma) on his head right? There's multiple other links as well between them.

Although, I'm not sure where you're getting Naaraayana from Thursday... He should be on Wednesday.

Anyways, the primary links to the Devataas are thus:

वह्न्यम्बुशिखिजा विष्णुविढौजः शचिका द्विज ।
सूर्यादीनां खगानां च देवा ज्ञेयाः क्रमेण च ॥ १८॥ - Brhat Parashara Hora Shastra 2/3/4(depending on version).18 (The location is not very well defined due to the length of chapters and so on in different versions.)

Translation: Agni, Aapa (Varuna), Kaartikeya, Vishnu, Indra, Indraani, Brahma are the Devas of the sky-movers starting from Surya, down the steps.

This is further linked based on similar qualities in Puranas to various devis and devas. For that, you'll need to read them though.

Since I took the example of Mangala already, Hanumaan is linked to him since he's related to Varaha Avataara (related to Vaayu), moreover, he rules over strength and war and so on.

Comment: Could you add sources for other things?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Sure, I added what I had lying around, in terms of sources.